# Making tables in r to show difference

Tags: r

```
Year        Cities   generosity     economic        culture         hp
2000    Seoul   1.23788 0.63376 0.86027 0.25497
2000    Mexico  1.29704 0.62433 0.89042 0.33088
2000    Guangzh 0.91451 0.48181 0.81444 0.14074
2000    Beijing 1.24711 0.54604 0.86179 0.40105
2000    Cairo   1.23287 0.49049 0.69702 0.14574
2000    New Yor 1.21963 0.61583 0.91894 0.28034
2000    Kolkata 1.36948 0.61777 0.89533 0.45901
2000    Moscow  1.28566 0.5845  0.89667 0.2225
2000    Bangkok 1.12575 0.64157 0.80925 0.26428
2000    Buenos  1.28548 0.59625 0.90943 0.51912
2000    Shenzhe 1.25596 0.42908 0.72052 0.05841
2000    Dhaka   1.02    0.54252 1.02525 0.31105
2000    Lagos   1.1985  0.5421  0.79661 0.24434
2000    Istanbu 1.29937 0.61477 0.89186 0.28214
2000    Osaka   1.12447 0.44132 0.85857 0.33363
2000    Karachi 1.0786  0.6404  0.79733 0.32573
2003    Seoul   0.94675 0.51697 0.81658 0.08185
2003    Mexico  0.91612 0.48827 0.29924 0.19591
2003    Guangzh 0.88588 0.35068 0.7689  0.13748
2003    Beijing 1.00964 0.20107 0.74836 0.19231
2003    Cairo   1.13935 0.51469 0.87519 0.13719
2003    New Yor 1.09562 0.29671 0.72437 0.18226
2003    Kolkata 1.03516 0.62545 0.58114 0.24991
2003    Moscow  0.64095 0.41691 0.60954 0.07172
2003    Bangkok 0.80434 0.35733 0.81325 0.14272
2003    Buenos  0.91916 0.09245 0.79081 0.24808
2003    Shenzhe 1.17202 0.57672 0.66825 0.21684
2003    Dhaka   1.3006  0.43626 0.60268 0.3323
2003    Lagos   0.92933 0.07699 0.88213 0
2003    Istanbu 0.80001 0.33916 0.83947 0.21854
2003    Osaka   1.20215 0.32112 0.75905 0.128
2003    Karachi 0.95348 0.40148 0.6951  0.23027
```

How would I create a table with the 5 cities with the largest positive value of the difference between their 2003 economic and their 2000 economic score? using base r or dplyr? Im keep having issues since i cant exclude the other columns for some reason.

Comment: By *"positive value of the difference"* do you mean absolute value? Or to discard the negative differences?

Comment: Seems to have deleted my previous comment. Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Generally, you would need to pivot_longer your data to wide format, then calculate the year differences and filter based on the result. And if need be you can reshape back with pivot_longer (all from the tidyverse package).

Comment: *"Im keep having issues since i cant exclude the other columns for some reason"* you'll probably learn more if you show us your attempt and we can explain why it's not working.

Comment: Though I disagree with deschen - I don't think any pivoting is needed here. The data is already long - OP just wants to focus on the `economic` column.

Comment: True...didn't know the diff function from base R. Awesome, I can totally imagine how to get rid of many of my pivoting codes now.

Comment: Please don't deface your question. Once you ask a question on this site, your question and its code becomes property of the site as per the terms of service that you agreed to on joining the site.

Answer (score 2):

Only using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% filter(Year %in% c(2000,2003)) %>%
  arrange(Cities,Year) %>%
  group_by(Cities) %>%
  summarise(Diff=diff(economic)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(desc(Diff)) %>%
  top_n(5)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Cities      Diff
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 Shenzhe  0.148  
2 Cairo    0.0242 
3 Kolkata  0.00768
4 Dhaka   -0.106  
5 Seoul   -0.117
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L), Cities = c("Seoul", 
"Mexico", "Guangzh", "Beijing", "Cairo", "New Yor", "Kolkata", 
"Moscow", "Bangkok", "Buenos", "Shenzhe", "Dhaka", "Lagos", "Istanbu", 
"Osaka", "Karachi", "Seoul", "Mexico", "Guangzh", "Beijing", 
"Cairo", "New Yor", "Kolkata", "Moscow", "Bangkok", "Buenos", 
"Shenzhe", "Dhaka", "Lagos", "Istanbu", "Osaka", "Karachi"), 
    generosity = c(1.23788, 1.29704, 0.91451, 1.24711, 1.23287, 
    1.21963, 1.36948, 1.28566, 1.12575, 1.28548, 1.25596, 1.02, 
    1.1985, 1.29937, 1.12447, 1.0786, 0.94675, 0.91612, 0.88588, 
    1.00964, 1.13935, 1.09562, 1.03516, 0.64095, 0.80434, 0.91916, 
    1.17202, 1.3006, 0.92933, 0.80001, 1.20215, 0.95348), economic = c(0.63376, 
    0.62433, 0.48181, 0.54604, 0.49049, 0.61583, 0.61777, 0.5845, 
    0.64157, 0.59625, 0.42908, 0.54252, 0.5421, 0.61477, 0.44132, 
    0.6404, 0.51697, 0.48827, 0.35068, 0.20107, 0.51469, 0.29671, 
    0.62545, 0.41691, 0.35733, 0.09245, 0.57672, 0.43626, 0.07699, 
    0.33916, 0.32112, 0.40148), culture = c(0.86027, 0.89042, 
    0.81444, 0.86179, 0.69702, 0.91894, 0.89533, 0.89667, 0.80925, 
    0.90943, 0.72052, 1.02525, 0.79661, 0.89186, 0.85857, 0.79733, 
    0.81658, 0.29924, 0.7689, 0.74836, 0.87519, 0.72437, 0.58114, 
    0.60954, 0.81325, 0.79081, 0.66825, 0.60268, 0.88213, 0.83947, 
    0.75905, 0.6951), hp = c(0.25497, 0.33088, 0.14074, 0.40105, 
    0.14574, 0.28034, 0.45901, 0.2225, 0.26428, 0.51912, 0.05841, 
    0.31105, 0.24434, 0.28214, 0.33363, 0.32573, 0.08185, 0.19591, 
    0.13748, 0.19231, 0.13719, 0.18226, 0.24991, 0.07172, 0.14272, 
    0.24808, 0.21684, 0.3323, 0, 0.21854, 0.128, 0.23027)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

But what mentioned in comments about absolute difference should be taken into account as it is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following will get you close.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Cities) %>%
  arrange(Year) %>%
  summarise(diff = diff(economic), .groups = "drop") %>%
  arrange(desc(diff), Cities) %>%
  top_n(5)
```

If by *"positive value of the difference"* you mean the absolute differences, then wrap `abs()` around the `diff` above:

```
summarise(diff = abs(diff(economic)), .groups = "drop")
```

But if you want to discard the negative differences, pipe the `summarise` to `filter(diff >= 0)`.

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L), Cities = c("Seoul", 
"Mexico", "Guangzh", "Beijing", "Cairo", "New York", "Kolkata", 
"Moscow", "Bangkok", "Buenos", "Shenzhe", "Dhaka", "Lagos", "Istanbu", 
"Osaka", "Karachi", "Seoul", "Mexico", "Guangzh", "Beijing", 
"Cairo", "New York", "Kolkata", "Moscow", "Bangkok", "Buenos", 
"Shenzhe", "Dhaka", "Lagos", "Istanbu", "Osaka", "Karachi"), 
    generosity = c(1.23788, 1.29704, 0.91451, 1.24711, 1.23287, 
    1.21963, 1.36948, 1.28566, 1.12575, 1.28548, 1.25596, 1.02, 
    1.1985, 1.29937, 1.12447, 1.0786, 0.94675, 0.91612, 0.88588, 
    1.00964, 1.13935, 1.09562, 1.03516, 0.64095, 0.80434, 0.91916, 
    1.17202, 1.3006, 0.92933, 0.80001, 1.20215, 0.95348), economic = c(0.63376, 
    0.62433, 0.48181, 0.54604, 0.49049, 0.61583, 0.61777, 0.5845, 
    0.64157, 0.59625, 0.42908, 0.54252, 0.5421, 0.61477, 0.44132, 
    0.6404, 0.51697, 0.48827, 0.35068, 0.20107, 0.51469, 0.29671, 
    0.62545, 0.41691, 0.35733, 0.09245, 0.57672, 0.43626, 0.07699, 
    0.33916, 0.32112, 0.40148), culture = c(0.86027, 0.89042, 
    0.81444, 0.86179, 0.69702, 0.91894, 0.89533, 0.89667, 0.80925, 
    0.90943, 0.72052, 1.02525, 0.79661, 0.89186, 0.85857, 0.79733, 
    0.81658, 0.29924, 0.7689, 0.74836, 0.87519, 0.72437, 0.58114, 
    0.60954, 0.81325, 0.79081, 0.66825, 0.60268, 0.88213, 0.83947, 
    0.75905, 0.6951), hp = c(0.25497, 0.33088, 0.14074, 0.40105, 
    0.14574, 0.28034, 0.45901, 0.2225, 0.26428, 0.51912, 0.05841, 
    0.31105, 0.24434, 0.28214, 0.33363, 0.32573, 0.08185, 0.19591, 
    0.13748, 0.19231, 0.13719, 0.18226, 0.24991, 0.07172, 0.14272, 
    0.24808, 0.21684, 0.3323, 0, 0.21854, 0.128, 0.23027)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -32L))
```

Comment: Im getting errors that say `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
Selecting by Diff, how would I fix that?

Comment: @mikegh that's not an error or even a warning - it's an informative message that prints because the default behavior for `summarise` changed and the `dplyr` maintainers want to make sure users are aware of it. If you don't want it to print, using the `.groups` argument to `summarise` as the message states. See the `?summarise` help page for details.